# How to turn off ViewEncapsulation only for specific HTML element in the component in Angular

Tags: angular

I know I can disable ViewEncapsulation for the whole component with:

```
import { ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
...
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
```

However, I would like to keep the ViewEncapsulation on the component, but disable it only for some of the HTML elements in the component.

For example:

```html
<div>
...
  <p id="disable_view_encapsulation">...</p>
</div>
```

How I can disable ViewEncapsulation only for the `<p>` tag with `id="disable_view_encapsulation"`?

Comment: You could extract a component with the `<p id="disable_view_encapsulation">...</p>` and disable its encapsulation.

Comment: Hi @Joulukuusi. I have a lot of places where I would want this, so creating new component for each would add to much complexity in the code base.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite a tricky question because you're adding your styles so they're available for all elements.

The easiest way would be to change your styles to match what you need.

Another way is to create some kind of custom directive that would reset styles for chosen elements but oh well you're left with default styles. I don't see how many changes you need and how complex it would be so it's hard to say if we could generalize it in the directive.

Well, you could give it a try with a custom component wrapper, which would get your HTML as input and display it. If we have a new component we can set its ViewEncapsulation to a different value. However, in this case, you might end up with a strange style file.

To be honest I would rather make changes in styles if it is possible to keep code simple and not add more complexity to it.

Comment: Hi @Adrian, I actually want to disable it not because of styles, but because I have issue with Angular adding `_ngcontent-xxx` attribute on each HTML element. I am using some third party service for localization, and it expect my custom attribute on HTML elements, but because Angular adds `_ngcontent-xxx` attribute in addition I have an issue with localization logic. That is why I want to disable it only on specific HTML elements, so Angular would not add `_ngcontent-xxx` attribute to these elements.

Comment: Hi @NeNaD
Oh sorry, I might have understood it a bit differently.

Still, did you try to create a custom wrapper with ViewEncapsulation.None and just pass those elements to it? I'm not perfectly sure if it will help but as logic suggests what we need is to have a possibility to add ViewEncapsulation.None to chosen elements. I don't think there is some kind of magic property like encapsulation="false" to turn it off per element so it needs a custom solution.

To be sure I'm not suggesting to create one component per instance but instead to make one domain wrapper to solve it.

Comment: Hi @Adrain. Thanks for the suggestion. Definitely one custom wrapper sounds like a good work around. And yeah, I checked the docs and couldn't find anything like `encapsulation="false"`, but I thought to ask anyway, maybe someone had the similar issue and found some similar workaround. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap the element in a component that you want to re-use with its view encapsulation turned off. You can't disable it for singular elements, only an entire component. There is no other way to really get around this in your case. Strange that your localization is affected by the attribute applied to the element, I would suggesting investigating why this is, and see if anyone else is using it with Angular and how they got around it.

Comment: Hi @Christian, thanks for the suggestion! Yeah, one component wrapper sounds like a good work around. That is how that localization service works. It checks for the first attribute in the HTML element in order to name the variable. I have send them a message, but though to ask here for a workaround anyway. Thanks!